# Parse JSON URL - JSONException Error

Tags: java, android, json, gson, android-volley

Please could you give me a hand here, I am trying to parse a JSON file from a URL. Below is the code that i used to grab the file and initially just posted it to a TextView but now I want to parse the tags and use them?

```
private void postData(final String param, final TextView tv) {

    final RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JSONObject postReq = new JSONObject(Request.Method.GET, url_login, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("Error [" + error + "]");

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            System.out.println(headers);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    request.add(postReq);
}
```

an example of the JSON is below

```
{
“UserInfo”: {
    “User”: {
        “name”: “Craig”,
        “surname”: "Churchill",
        "userId": "1463353",
        "userAlias": "Craig"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) but have just failed constantly and just cannot get it right.

[image]

Comment: Please remove your comma at the end (after "Craig") ... and can you added your exception, it is useful, sometimes ...

Comment: last key-value pair not contain comma.

Comment: maybe it was the error ? :)

Comment: @biology.info jsonlint doesn't pass if it comes with a comma on the last key-value pair. But I´ve worked with some jsons with them and they don't crash.

Comment: guys, the comma on the end was a mistake, that was just a small snippet of the JSON and i just forgot the comma there. This JSON is used on a live environment at the moment which works fine for others.

Comment: [ALT+ENTER doesn't work?](http://selvin.pl/alt_enter.png)

Comment: look at the image, if you press ALT+ENTER on error IDE will "try to help"

Comment: Thanks! Learned something new! :D did not know that!! haha! see u can do the @Overrides as well!! nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    "UserInfo": {
        "User": {
            "name": "Craig",
            "surname": "Churchill",
            "userId": "1463353",
            "userAlias": "Craig"
        }
    }
}
```

It´s a valid json. I´ve tried it on http://jsonlint.com/ But you've got some double commas that have a weird encoding. I put the json above with a right doble comma enconding, since jsonlint was giving errors validating the json until I changed them.

The problem might be on how you're accesing the object and it´s childrens. Try this way.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONObject userObj = response.getJSONObject("UserInfo")
                            .getJSONObject("User");
        String name = userObj.getString("name");
        ...
    } catch (JSONException jsEx) {
        jsEx.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```